# How to divide a list of characters (that represents a word) into all possible (prefix, single_letter, suffix) triplets in CAML?

Tags: recursion, pattern-matching, ocaml

I defined a type "word" as a list of characters. I am trying to write a recursive function "divide_word" that takes one "word" as an argument and returns a list of triplets of all possible (prefix, single_letter, suffix) combinations of the "word".

Example of execution in OCAML:

```
assert( divide_word ['c';'o';'d';'e'] = [  ([],'c',['o';'d';'e']) ; (['c'],'o',['d';'e']) ; (['c','o'],'d',['e']) ; (['c','o','d'],'e',[])  ];;
```

I've tried writing the function, but it only returns the last possible combination. I know that I have to find a way to return an actual list and not just a single triplet, I tried to concatenate and also to write a separate function.

This is the code that I've written:

```
type word = char list;;

let rec divide_word (w:word) : (word*char*word) list =
  match w with
  | [] -> []
  | h::[] -> [([], h, [])]
  | h::t -> List.map (fun (fir, sec, th) -> (h::fir, sec, th)) (divide_word t);;
```

help! c:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there. In the last case of the pattern matching, you compute correctly all triplets where any character from the second to the last is used as separator, but you also have to add to that list the case where the first character (i.e. `h`) is the separator (hence the prefix empty and the suffix `t`).

Once this is done, you will probably notice that the case `h::[]` is in fact a particular case of `h::t`, thus need not to be treated apart in its own pattern.

Answer (score 0):

One particularly terse way to handle this using sequences top take from an drop from lists. `List.mapi` lets us keep track of our index in the list to know how many elements to take and drop.

```
# let rec divide_list lst =
    let lst_take n lst = lst |> List.to_seq |> Seq.take n |> List.of_seq in
    let lst_drop n lst = lst |> List.to_seq |> Seq.drop n |> List.of_seq in
    List.mapi (fun i x -> lst_take i lst, x, lst_drop (i+1) lst) lst;;
val divide_list : 'a list -> ('a list * 'a * 'a list) list = <fun>
# "hello" |> String.to_seq |> List.of_seq |> divide_list;;
- : (char list * char * char list) list =
[([], 'h', ['e'; 'l'; 'l'; 'o']); (['h'], 'e', ['l'; 'l'; 'o']);
 (['h'; 'e'], 'l', ['l'; 'o']); (['h'; 'e'; 'l'], 'l', ['o']);
 (['h'; 'e'; 'l'; 'l'], 'o', [])]
```

But we could also see this as an opportunity to apply a zipper data structure which can keep track of not only the remaining list, but also where we've been.

```
# type 'a zipper = Z of 'a list * 'a list

  let z_advance = function
    | Z (f, []) as z -> z
    | Z (f, x::xs) -> Z (x :: f, xs)

  let z_init lst = Z ([], lst)

  let divide_list lst =
    let[@tail_mod_cons] rec aux = function
      | Z (f, []) -> []
      | Z (f, x::xs) as z -> (List.rev f, x, xs) :: aux (z_advance z)
    in
    lst |> z_init |> aux;;
type 'a zipper = Z of 'a list * 'a list
val z_advance : 'a zipper -> 'a zipper = <fun>
val z_init : 'a list -> 'a zipper = <fun>
val divide_list : 'a list -> ('a list * 'a * 'a list) list = <fun>
# "hello" |> String.to_seq |> List.of_seq |> divide_list;;
- : (char list * char * char list) list =
[([], 'h', ['e'; 'l'; 'l'; 'o']); (['h'], 'e', ['l'; 'l'; 'o']);
 (['h'; 'e'], 'l', ['l'; 'o']); (['h'; 'e'; 'l'], 'l', ['o']);
 (['h'; 'e'; 'l'; 'l'], 'o', [])]
```